# Replace File to Base64 using Regex

Tags: python, regex, base64, byte, encode

I am using this code to replace a file to base64 using Regex

```py
import re
import base64

file = "test.txt"
with open(file, "r") as f:
    # Encode the file to base64
    encoded_file = base64.b64encode(f.read().encode("utf-8"))

string = "string"
pattern = "pattern"
updt_str = re.sub(pattern, encoded_file, string)
```

Doing this, I am getting the error:

```py
TypeError sequence item 1 expected str instance bytes found
```

I need to replace the str to this base64 encoded file. Is there anyway to do it? Thank you for your attention.

Comment: I think you have a typo in your example. `updt_str = re.sub(pattern, encoded_file, string)` should be `updt_str = re.sub(pattern, string, encoded_file)`. Once I made that change then I could reproduce your error. It was fixed by making `string` and `pattern` bytes to match `encoded_file`. e.g. `string = b"string"` and `pattern = b"pattern"`

Answer (score 1):

`b64encode` returns a `bytes` object. You have two choices for using `re` with that: you can `decode` that back to a regular `str` string, or you can use byte strings for the other parameters.

Comment: Huuuum... But decoding back to a regular str the file stills on b64?

Comment: @AntonioCosta yes, because the character set used by base-64 is limited it will not matter if it's encoded or decoded.  It's only a requirement of `re` that you be consistent with the types of strings you feed into it.